# Error while viewing report in JasperServer and iReport

Tags: java, jasperserver

I have customized `JasperServer`. 
I am using `PostgreSQL` database with `JasperServer`. I have imported reports. However I am not able to view those reports in `JasperServer` as well as `iReport`. 
When I view it like xml it shows a long number.

Please help me to resolve this issue if anyone have configured **JasperServer** with **Postgres** database.

***Note: There is no issue when I use MySQL database***

It throwing following exception when I try to execute the report.
Error loading the report template

*Message:*
        **net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.**

*Level:*
        SEVERE

*Stack Trace:*

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:245)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:216)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:87)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:505)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Content is not allowed in prolog.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1039)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1647)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:241)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML(JRXmlLoader.java:228)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:216)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlLoader.reloadJasperDesign(JrxmlLoader.java:87)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.JrxmlVisualView.run(JrxmlVisualView.java:505)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

Comment: Did you check the report with help of iReport using integration with JasperServer?

Comment: And what about samples from JasperServer? Are they work?

Comment: This is known issue: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=88589

Comment: Ya.. same error at i-Report. I have not uploaded the sample reports. I have uploaded the minimal configuration with my own reports.

Comment: What do you mean `Xml has content as very long number`? Can you post the snippet?

Comment: Its very long. I will paste as much as possible.Its about 56000 character 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

Comment: It gets damaged after upload. I have two jasperserver. One with mysql and one with postgres. I m facing issue with postgres and not with mysql :) It work fine with mysql..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5190/discussion-between-alex-k-and-dinesh)

Comment: May be you should add information from comments to the original post (deploy steps and the result - damaged report)?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is always caused by the invalid XML content in the beginning element. For example, extra small dot “.” in the beginning of XML element.

Any characters before the < ? xml…. will cause above org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog error message.[Reference](http://www.mkyong.com/java/sax-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/).

Comment: I knew that. But facing issue with postgres database. Report is in the form of xml. There is issue while uploading the report. Xml has content as very long number..

Comment: @Dinesh Yeah but you have to validate the overall xml yourself. you can use this [XML Validator](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp). the same error appear  as well when the parser found the xml file empty.

Comment: Thanks.. But the xml itself is invalid. It get changed after upload.

Comment: This is strange but true.. I have posted content as comment as reply  for comment from Alex..